# Plasma 5 keyboard "Alt+1"

Tags: kde, plasma, kde5, plasma-5

I use KDE plasma 5.10.1 .

I use Alt+1 ... Alt+10 to change tabs in web browsers or konsole .
my problem is Alt+1 not working in plasma desktop and i always replace /usr/bin/kglobalaccel5 to /usr/bin/kglobalaccel for fix this problem .

**For a long time plasma 5 have this problem .**
Why kglobalaccel5 can not handle Alt+1 ?
note : I dont use NumPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disabling **Alt+`** and **Alt+~** shortcut will works but we will remove a good shortcut!
the better way is to edit the "ir" keyboard layout manually and remove the accent from key 1.

Follow this steps:

- sudo vi /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/ir
- find a line containing this:

```
key <AE01> { [ Farsi_1,     exclam,              grave,                   1       ] };
```

- remove "grave,".
  the new line should be:

```
key <AE01> { [ Farsi_1,     exclam,              1       ] };
```

- save and exit
- remove ir keyboard and add again
- Finished!

Answer (score 7):

There is a shortcut in
*System Setting/Shortcuts/Global Shortcuts* for
*Walk Through Windows of Current Application (Reverse)*, which is set to **alt+~**, if you delete that shortcut (i.e. set it to custom and leave it empty, then press apply) you will be able to use **alt+1** in other applications, like you case with the browser.

(Tested under different Linux distro with KDE Plasma.)

Edit: on my keyboard layout **~** is on key **1**, maybe that is why it worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me. Although I had to disable "Walk through windows of current application" which was the back tick: Alt+`
I was really annoying, thanks for the fix.